# Check if parent is ltr or rtl

Tags: html, css

is it possible to check if parent's css is ltr or rtl and then apply different styles to child element?

for example I have:

```
<div class="parent ltr"><div class="child"></div></div>
```

and

```
<div class="parent rtl"><div class="child"></div></div>
```

I would like to set different style to child class based in parent div's ltr or rtl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just specify different styles based on whether your child is inside `rtl` or `ltr` parent:

```
.ltr .child { ... details of child of ltr }
.rtl .child { ... details of child of rtl }
```

Or you can use "direct descendant" in your CSS for more tight control:

```
.ltr > .child { ... details of child of ltr }
.rtl > .child { ... details of child of rtl }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.ltr .child { /* some styles here */}
.rtl .child { /* other styles here */}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code sure:

```
div.parent.ltr div.child { /* one set of rules */ }
div.parent.rtl div.child { /* a different set of rules */ }
```